# Syntax error in node modules file on installation of vite

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, frontend, vite

I created a new vite project with:
npm install vite@latest

then chose my project name, selected React and Javascript + SWC
then npm install
but got this error when running: npm run dev

```
npm does not support Node.js v15.5.1
You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

> frontend_vite@0.0.0 dev
> vite

.../frontend_vite/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-R0I0XnyH.js:38336
const inlineImportRE = /(?<!(?<!\.\.)\.)\bimport\s*\(("(?:[^"]|(?<=\\)")*"|'(?:[^']|(?<=\\)')*')\)/dg;
                       ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Tried installing vite and running my project locally but immediately got this error. I have another vite project i created a few months ago, and i didn't encounter this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the version of nodeJS is not supported for your setup from Vite, there are maybe some libraries within Vite core that need a major version of NodeJS.

If you have other projects that need NodeJS 15.x.x you can start using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to run multiple versions of NodeJS on your machine. If not, you can just upgrade your NodeJS version or reinstall it with the latest version.